# converting many to many to one to many relationship in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 columns in a table-

```
Parentid                                                   ID       
3_UExpiZlgpglxaqM141IoDXtusBlpEcGjruIA                     1319760694.1580758970
3_UExpiZlgpglxaqM141IoDXtusBlpEcGjruIA                     667017325.1580160238
SorWqMp9k2NbOMeop-GomrzOTGerTDTnGzq6Ig                     667017325.1580160238
SorWqMp9k2NbOMeop-GomrzOTGerTDTnGzq6Ig                     109851370.1575305452
SorWqMp9k2NbOMeop-GomrzOTGerTDTnGzq6Ig                     1319760694.1580758970
7KoIW56HitFcs5y9huhfmh2RQgUXBdtrY0w                        1319760694.1580758970
```

as rows 3,4,5 have the same parentid - SorWqMp9k2NbOMeop-GomrzOTGerTDTnGzq6Ig- I want to select only  G3 and ID1, ID2, ID3.

**My aim is to map maximum number of ID's to one Parentid.**

How can I do that in bigquery?

Comment: can you explicitly show expected result please! and elaborate more on the logic! looks like ID1 also has G1 as a parent ... and the rest of IDN have other parents - so what the logic of selecting ones vs. others ?

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I made changes as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

According to you question, you want to select only one ***Parentid*** and the corresponding ***IDs*** in a repeated field.

You can achieve that using the [ARRAY_AGG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) method, it returns an *ARRAY* of expression values. You can also add distinct to the method so you only return unique ***IDs***. I used the sample data you provided and the syntax you be as follows.

```
#standadSQL
SELECT
  Parentid,
  ARRAY_AGG(Distinct ID) AS ID
FROM
  `project_id.dataset.source_table`
GROUP BY
  Parentid
```

And the output,

[image]